# ListView groupby and also preserve original items

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox, grouping, collectionview

I have a viewmodel in my wpf application like this:

```
Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>(); //main list

Students.Add(new Student_Senior { Name = "GG", Age = 14 });
Students.Add(new Student_Senior { Name = "VV", Age = 20 , IsGenius = true});
Students.Add(new Student_Senior { Name = "YY", Age = 23 });
Students.Add(new Student_Senior { Name = "BB", Age = 18 });
Students.Add(new Student_Senior { Name = "CC", Age = 11, IsGenius = true });
Students.Add(new Student_Senior { Name = "WW", Age = 20 });
```

I would like to display my listbox in output ui like this (based on IsGenius = true):

```
-----------------------------
Genius: True
VV  20  true
CC 11 true

All:
GG  14 false
VV  20  true
YY 23 false
BB 18 false
CC 11 true
WW 20 false
------------------------------
```

i tried doing this:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="StudentGroup"  Source="{Binding Path=Students}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
          <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="IsGenius" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
      </CollectionViewSource>

<ListView DataContext="{StaticResource StudentGroup}">
          <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
              <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                  <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                          <Expander.Header>
                            <DockPanel>
                              <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                          </Expander.Header>
                          <Expander.Content>
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                          </Expander.Content>
                        </Expander>
                      </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                  </Setter>
                </Style>
              </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
          </ListView.GroupStyle>
```

But this groups it based on IsGenius=true and IsGenius=false as two distinct groups. I want to preserve the original (full) rows below the IsGenius = true group.
Has anyone tried this before!.. please let me know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are looking for a *stable sort*.

Comment: @aybe: Thanks for reply. I updated the question. I am not looking for a sorted list/entries here. I am just looking for a grouped and all the un-grouped(original) entries together.

Comment: Okay then so why don't you make a style out of this list view and simply add another list view below ? this would be simplest/fastest way to achieve this.

Comment: Yes i thought about that but I was thinking if something like this was possible. Cool.. thx

Comment: You could even use an items control whose item panel is list view, it would have to bind to an object with items and grouping properties. That is, bind list views to a list of groupable items. I guess you get the point.

Comment: I am afraid an object may only belong to one group when you group using a `PropertyGroupDescription`.  You probably want to implement your own custom grouping.

Comment: @mm8: Any example/link you can suggest for custom grouping! Thx

Comment: @Joe: Group the `ItemsSource` and define a `DataTemplate` for the groups and another one for the items.